# PostgreSQL - Generate series using subqueries

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, date, series

Using PostgreSQL, I need to accomplish the following scenario. I have a table called routine, where I store start_date and end_date columns. I have another table called exercises, where I store all the data related with each exercise and finally, I have a table called routine_exercise where I create the relationship between the routine and the exercise. Each routine can have seven days (one day indicates the day of the week, e.g: 1 means Monday, etc) of exercises and each day can have one or more exercise. For example:

**Exercise Table**

| Exercise ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Exercise 1 |
| 2 | Exercise 2 |
| 3 | Exercise 3 |

**Routine Table**

| Routine ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Routine 1 |
| 2 | Routine 2 |
| 3 | Routine 3 |

**Routine_Exercise Table**

| Exercise ID | Routine ID | Day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |

The thing that I'm trying to do is generate a series from start_date to end_date (e.g 03-25-2020 to 05-25-2020, two months) and assign to each date the number of day it supposed to work.
For example, using the data in the **Routine_Exercise Table** the user should only workout days: 1,2,3,4, so I would like to attach that number to each date. For example, something like this:

**Expected Result**

| Date | Number |
| --- | --- |
| 03-25-2020 | 1 |
| 03-26-2020 | 2 |
| 03-27-2020 | 3 |
| 03-28-2020 | 4 |
| 03-29-2020 | null |
| 03-30-2020 | null |
| 03-31-2020 | null |
| 04-01-2020 | 1 |
| 04-02-2020 | 2 |
| 04-03-2020 | 3 |
| 04-04-2020 | 4 |
| 04-05-2020 | null |

Any suggestions or different ideas on how to implement this? Another solution that doesn't require series?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the dates between start and end input dates using `generate_series` and then do `left join` with your `routine_exercise` table as follows:

```
SELECT t.d, re.day
  FROM generate_series(timestamp '2020-03-25', timestamp '2020-05-25',
                       interval  '1 day') AS t(d)
  left join (select distinct day from Routine_Exercise re WHERE ROUTINE_ID = 1) re
    on mod(extract(day from (t.d -timestamp '2020-03-25')), 7) + 1 = re.day;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, that works but only for the first seven records. It should repeat the same pattern from start_date to end_date. For example, on this date (2020-04-01) should be day = 1 and so on. Do you know how to implement that? Once again, thank you, it really helped me.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly. Excellent solution and the performance is great!